# In azure functions, is it possible to use an app setting as part of path of a binding?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have the following `function.json` file:

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "route": "resource/{resourceId}",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "ativo",
      "path": "data/{appsettings_current_date}/{resourceId}.json",
      "connection": "mock_STORAGE",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, I want to access a data from a blob storage that is stored in a folder which its name should be a parameter.

Example, if appsettings_current_date = '20171003' and resourceId = 1, the binding should look to the file in the path `data/20171003/1.json`. The problem is, the variable `appsettings_current_date` should be an application setting that is changed in the dashboard. Is it possible?

I was planning to change this configuration once a day, as soon as I made some calculations and stored some data in the blob storage.

If it is not possible, what is the better alternative for it? I may need think different in those situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use a percent sign to access the app setting:

```
{
  "type": "blob",
  "name": "ativo",
  "path": "data/%appsettings_current_date%/%resourceId%.json",
  "connection": "mock_STORAGE",
  "direction": "in"
}
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#resolving-app-settings